# Where is UITableViewCell being put back to queue?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am currently working on update to an app that I didn't make myself.

In it, there is a highly customized table view that is used for horizontal scrolling through images with 3 images showing at once and enabled paging.

The issue is that sometimes they appear white and I think that is because they are returned by `dequeueReusableCell` while they are still visible. (So table view is reusing the cell that, because is still visible, shouldn't be reused.)

Since there is usually not very many cells in that table, I tried with a workaround that alloc's and init's a new cell every single time instead of dequeuing an old one and so far it works fine (for a small table).

However, this is not a good solution and I want to do it the "right" way.

I don't know how is it decided whether cell should be put back to queue or not.

What should I do to stop cells from being queued for reuse?

Comment: Is your table view rotated 90 degrees to allow the horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am using this https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView

Comment: Are you saying they're white when the come on screen or they come on screen with images and then turn white while still on screen?

Comment: Both happens. Also, when I move left and right for a while, move to another view controller and back etc. all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want the cells to be reused, do it the way you already did. It is not recommended to be not reusing `UITableViewCells`. The reusing-technique saves memory.

But when you tableView is not highly memory-expensive, do it like this. It is **the** way not "disable" reusing.

It sounds like it's because the tableView is rotated by 90° to achieve horizontal scrolling. So iOS thinks that the cell which got scrolled an amount out `x` pixels and must be located offscreen and can be reused. This is what I presume.

When your update addresses iOS 6.0 and later I'd recommend switching to `UICollectionView` which is very similar to `UITableView` but has the ability of totally customized flow layouts (this is the term you'd google for).

When my presumption is correct, another *possible* solution could be to use two reusable IDs and alternate them so that a cell got enough "space" to scroll:

```
if([indexPath row] % 2 == 0) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierOne];
}
else {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierTwo];
}
```

But I **REALLY** don't now if I'm right with this guess :)

Comment: I have to support iOS 5. :( I now also found case where the table is bigger and when I scroll through it fast enough all 3 images become white.

Comment: Really? [This version spread chart][1] from the [Apple Developer Resources][2] could help you convince your customers so you can move to iOS 6 :) [1]: https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/devcenter/ios/checklist/images/chart.png [2]: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/

Comment: But your comment sounds like the images are not loading fast enough. Are they loaded from a webServer?

Comment: Yes, they are downloaded from a server. But I have them loaded and i.e. when I start scrolling, middle one of my 3 images disappears (becomes white), even though it was there a second ago and it is still fully visible on screen.

Comment: Just use PSTCollectionview open source library to your project in order to support Collectionviews on ios5. it switches to native collectionview automatically depending on clients ios version. All the api is %100 compatible with original uicollectionview. Quite mature and flawless. https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView